# HttpServlet Error in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote a simple java code for login screen.
Here is the code:
`Login.java`

```
package Banking;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Client extends HttpServlet
{
    Connection con;
    String s3="",s4="";

    public void init(ServletConfig sc)throws ServletException
    { 
     try{
          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
          con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:thin","sys","orcl as sysdba");
           }catch(Exception ee){System.out.println(ee);}
    }

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
   {
          PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
          res.setContentType("text/html");

          String s1=req.getParameter("user");
          String s2=req.getParameter("pwd");
  try{
                Statement st=con.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select name from pass where name=' "+s1+" ' ");      

     while(rs.next())
      {   
                s3=rs.getString(1);
                s4=rs.getString(2);   
    }


      if(s1.equals("")||s2.equals(""))
      {   
         pw.println("invalid");

      res.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080p/tball.gif");
      }
          else 
       {
          PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into pass values(?,?)" );
          pst.setString(1,s1);
          pst.setString(2,s2);
          pst.execute();
          res.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/welcome.html"); 
        }
  }catch(Exception e){res.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/invalid.html");} 
 }
}
```

`Data.java`

```
package Banking;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Client2 extends GenericServlet
{
  Connection con;
   public void init(ServletConfig sc)throws ServletException
   { 
    try{
     Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin","sys","orcl as sysdba");
                    }catch(Exception ee){System.out.println(ee);}
}

   public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
{    boolean j=true;
      String s1=req.getParameter("t1");
      String s2=req.getParameter("t2");
      String s3=req.getParameter("t3");    
     String s4=req.getParameter("r");
     String s5=req.getParameter("s"); 
     String s6=req.getParameter("t4");
      String s7=req.getParameter("t5");
      String s8=req.getParameter("t6");
      String s9=req.getParameter("s1");
     String s10=req.getParameter("t7");
     String s11=req.getParameter("t8");
     String s12=req.getParameter("t9");


try{
            PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("insert into entry values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" );

pst.setString(1,s1);pst.setString(2,s2);pst.setString(3,s3);pst.setString(4,s4);
pst.setString(5,s5);pst.setString(6,s6);pst.setString(7,s7);pst.setString(8,s8);
pst.setString(9,s9);pst.setString(10,s10);pst.setString(11,s11);pst.setString(12,s12);
pst.execute();

}
catch(Exception e)
{System.out.println(e);}
PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
res.setContentType("text/html");
 pw.println("inserted.into table.."); 
 }
}
```

I'm getting so many errors like:

```
GenericServlet cannot be resolved to a type data.java   /Myproject/src/Banking  line 8  Java Problem
HttpServlet cannot be resolved to a type    Login.java  /Myproject/src/Banking  line 7  Java Problem
HttpServlet cannot be resolved to a type    login.java  /banking/src/banking    line 9  Java Problem
HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type Login.java  /Myproject/src/Banking  line 20 Java Problem
HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type login.java  /banking/src/banking    line 22 Java Problem
HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved to a type    Login.java  /Myproject/src/Banking  line 20 Java Problem
HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved to a type    login.java  /banking/src/banking    line 22 Java Problem
ServletConfig cannot be resolved to a type  Login.java  /Myproject/src/Banking  line 12 Java Problem
ServletConfig cannot be resolved to a type  data.java   /Myproject/src/Banking  line 11 Java Problem
ServletConfig cannot be resolved to a type  login.java  /banking/src/banking    line 14 Java Problem
ServletException cannot be resolved to a type   Login.java  /Myproject/src/Banking  line 12 Java Problem
ServletException cannot be resolved to a type   Login.java  /Myproject/src/Banking  line 20 Java Problem
ServletException cannot be resolved to a type   data.java   /Myproject/src/Banking  line 11 Java Problem
ServletException cannot be resolved to a type   data.java   /Myproject/src/Banking  line 19 Java Problem
ServletException cannot be resolved to a type   login.java  /banking/src/banking    line 14 Java Problem
ServletException cannot be resolved to a type   login.java  /banking/src/banking    line 22 Java Problem
ServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type data.java   /Myproject/src/Banking  line 19 Java Problem
ServletResponse cannot be resolved to a type    data.java   /Myproject/src/Banking  line 19 Java Problem
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved Login.java  /Myproject/src/Banking  line 3  Java Problem
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved Login.java  /Myproject/src/Banking  line 5  Java Problem
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved data.java   /Myproject/src/Banking  line 4  Java Problem
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved data.java   /Myproject/src/Banking  line 6  Java Problem
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved login.java  /banking/src/banking    line 4  Java Problem
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved login.java  /banking/src/banking    line 6  Java Problem
The public type Client must be defined in its own file  Login.java  /Myproject/src/Banking  line 7  Java Problem
The public type Client2 must be defined in its own file data.java   /Myproject/src/Banking  line 8  Java Problem
```

How can I resolve those errors?

Comment: When you get the error?

Comment: A little off the topic suggestion use `if("".equals(s1)||"".equals(s2))` in place of  `if(s1.equals("")||s2.equals(""))`

Comment: @Jens: Got it while writing the code

Comment: @SpringLearner: I replaced it

Comment: Change your classname from `Login.java` to `Client.java` and `Data.java` to `Client2.java`.  public class should be declared in a java file with the same name as that of **class**.  So in your case **Client class** must be in `Client.java` and **Client2 class** in `Client2.java`

Comment: You need to add in your classpath libraries provided by your application server, like `j2ee.jar` (if websphere) or `servlet-api.jar` (if tomcat)

Comment: It seems your code and IDE not referenced your servlet-api.jar. Check your lib folder whether jar is present or not. You can add it via build path.

Comment: Class naming as Deepika said, also the jars for servlet-api.jar looks like it isn't being detected. If you are compiling this via command prompt, use "-cp" then the path off the libraries to it to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure libs are added? Check your build-path.

Answer (score 1):

You need to name your classes as follow :

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet
{
  // you
}



public class Data extends GenericServlet
{
   // .... you code here 
}
```

Because your files are named `Login.java` and `Data.java`